# MVC5 / Razor TextAreaFor null value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a very basic `@Html.TextAreaFor()` on a form, and for some reason, the text area's value never makes it to my controller.

**VIEW**

```
<p class="SmallText">(Multiple Entries Allowed)</p>
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.quickSearch, new { cols = 30, @rows = 5 })
```

**VIEW-MODEL**

```
public String quickSearch;
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult FindRecord(FindRecordViewModel Model)
{       
    var ImNotCrazy = Model.quickSearch;
}
```

The problem is that when I debug `Model.quickSearch` is always null and never has a value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your view model has to have Properties, not fields, to work properly with model binding. So change `public String quickSearch;` to `public String quickSearch { get; set; }`.

Also, you should use standard naming conventions and change the name of the field to `QuickSearch`

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe I missed the obvious answer right in front me. That was it! The old second pair of eyes thing ;)  As far as the naming convention goes, I didn't actually write this code, just helping a coworker figure out why it wasn't working.

Comment: @mituw16 That would be a third pair of eyes then ;)